# Need help on saving a song on Whatsapp on a Lumia 520

Tags: lumia

How does one save a song that he/she has received via Whatsapp on the Lumia "520" Windows Phone?

Answer (score 1):

You can't till now windows phone does not offer the feature of saving an audio sent over whatsapp. Images and videos can be saved but not audio.